# WPF Interface becomes unresponsive when clearing source of CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where I communicate with a second application via TCP sockets. Each message sent and received has a given length and information, which is wrapped into an object.

After handling the message, this object is added to an ObservableList, which is (oneway) bound to a CollectionViewSource. This CollectionViewSource is the Itemsource of a Datagrid. Additionally, the CollectionViewSource has a filter which can be set with several toggleButtons. When the connection is closed, the list should be cleared for further use after reconnecting.

I tested this setup and especially the filtering up to a few thousand entries and it seems to work fine. Except if I clear the ObservableCollection, the whole interface becomes unresponsive, slow and setting the filter will spike the processing power used up to 60%, even for 10 objects in the list.

Clearing the ObservableCollection doesn't seem to update the Interface, only overwriting the Collection with a new object.

I also tried to change properties in XAML, like binding mode or read only, but this does change nothing.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="telegramList" 
                      Source="{Binding Path=LogManager.TList, mode=OneWay }"  
                      Filter="telegramFilter">
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource telegramList}}" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" x:Name="
```

Edit: Here is the LogManager, and the functions accessing the list. LogTelegram() can be called from either a Socket Callback, or directly from the main thread, before the message object is queued for sending.

```
public class LogManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private ObservableCollection<ImmutableTelegram> tList;
        public ObservableCollection<ImmutableTelegram> TList { get { return tList; } set { tList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TList"); } }

        public void logTelegram(Telegram512 telegram)
        {
            if (!Model.Instance.gui.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Model.Instance.gui.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
                {
                    logTelegramDelegate(telegram);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                logTelegramDelegate(telegram);
            }
        }

        private void logTelegramDelegate(Telegram512 telegram)
        {
            if (telegram.TELETYPE == Telegram512.Types.XX)
                TList.Add(new ImmutableTelegram(telegram));

            if(TList != null)
                TList.Add(new ImmutableTelegram(telegram));

        }

        public void clearTelegramLog()
        {
            TList = null;
        }

        public void createTelegramLog()
        {
            TList = new ObservableCollection<ImmutableTelegram>();
        }
}
```

Here is also the filter function and one state changed listener for a toggle button.

```
private void dataGridFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = e.Item as Telegram512;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            e.Accepted = true;

            if (obj.TELETYPE == Telegram512.Types.LF && this.lfToggle.IsChecked == false)
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

private void lfToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(telegramDataGrid.ItemsSource != null)
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(telegramDataGrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context code. The XAML snippet you posted is definitely not enough for investigation. Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem, but having a setter on an `ObservableCollection` of a view-model is *usually* a mistake.  The usual pattern is to have a setter only, and instantiate it in the constructor, from then on, only adding / removing / clearing operations are done on the collection.  Since the instance its self doesn't change, it doesn't need to raise `PropertyChanged` either (the collection internally raises `CollectionChanged` events as items move around.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for the suggestion! I alredy tried to follow this pattern but I did try to see if it makes a difference if the list is set to null and then newly instantiated when pressing a button.